# Why am I getting AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, django-views

I was testing Django http output.

In the Django shell, the output is normal, but when an http request is sent, AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE

# Create your models here.

class Actor(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(auto_now=False, null=True)
    movies = models.ManyToManyField('Movie', through='Actor_Movie')
    class Meta:
        db_table="actors"


class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    release_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, null=True)
    running_time = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table="movies"

class Actor_Movie(models.Model):
    actors = models.ForeignKey('Actor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    movies = models.ForeignKey('Movie', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
        path('',MoviesView.as_view()),
        ]
```

views.py

```
from django.http import request
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from .models import Actor, Movie, Actor_Movie
import json

# Create your views here.

class MoviesView(View):
    def get(self,request):
        ac = Actor.objects.all()
        results=[]
        for a in ac:
            c =[i for i in ac.movies.values("title")]
            results.append(
                {
                    "first_name" : a.first_name,
                    "movies" : c,
                }
            )
        return JsonResponse({"result":results}, status = 201)
```

server request command

```
http -v GET 127.0.0.1:8000/movies
```

output screen

```
WARNINGS:
?: (urls.W002) Your URL pattern '/dogs' has a route beginning with a '/'. Remove this slash as it is unnecessary. If this pattern is targeted in an include(), ensure the include() pattern has a trailing '/'.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
November 16, 2021 - 14:55:33
Django version 3.2.9, using settings 'dogs.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Internal Server Error: /movies
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jinsungpark/miniconda3/envs/dogs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/jinsungpark/miniconda3/envs/dogs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/jinsungpark/miniconda3/envs/dogs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jinsungpark/miniconda3/envs/dogs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jinsungpark/wecode/dogs/movies/views.py", line 15, in get
    c =[i for i in ac.movies.values("title")]
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'movies'
[16/Nov/2021 14:55:36] "GET /movies HTTP/1.1" 500 69966
```

I want to print some movies and actors, it works fine in the shell.

```
In [81]: b = Movie.objects.get(id=1)

In [82]: b.actor_set.values("last_name")
Out[82]: <QuerySet [{'last_name': '정우'}]>

In [83]: a.movies.values("title")
Out[83]: <QuerySet [{'title': '암살'}, {'title': '신과 함께'}]>

In [84]: e = a.movies.values("title")

In [85]: [i for i in e]
Out[85]: [{'title': '암살'}, {'title': '신과 함께'}]

In [86]: [i for i in e]
Out[86]: [{'title': '암살'}, {'title': '신과 함께'}]

In [87]: e = a.movies.values_list("title")

In [88]: [i for i in e]
Out[88]: [('암살',), ('신과 함께',)]

In [89]: c= [i for i in e]

In [90]: c
Out[90]: [('암살',), ('신과 함께',)]

In [91]:
```

Comment: On the line that is throwing the exception: `c =[i for i in ac.movies.values("title")]`, shouldn't be a iteration  of `a` object? `c =[i for i in a.movies.values("title")]`

Comment: Even without repetition, the result is the same.
"movies" : ac.movies.values("title"),

Comment: What do you mean with `Even without repetition`? If you do `ac.movies`, `ac` is not an Actor object, is a list of actor objects, the result of your `Actor.objects.all()` that get all the actors. Then you do the `for a in ac:`, where every `a` will be an Actor, and is the Actor who contains their movies, not the set of Actors.

Comment: It meant not repeating 'ac.movies.values'. I want to print the title to which the actor belongs in the movie object connected by first_name and manytomany using Actor.

Comment: Then, I pretty sure that when you get the movies list in line 15 from `/movies/views.py` you should use `c =[i for i in a.movies.values("title")]`. Notice the **a** instead **an**

Comment: Re-creating the DB works fine. I'll have to look for the cause more.